# Loading 600billion records from 1 hive table into another

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have a hive external table in 1 database with around 600 billion records and 100 columns. I need to copy the data as is to same table in other database. I am trying to write a spark code but it is taking forever. is there any recommendation how I would write the code? I am new to spark!

Answer (score 1):

Do not copy, let it sit where it is. Create external table in another database with location pointing to the data location.

```
USE YOUR_DATABASE;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc ... LOCATION 'hdfs://your/data';
```

Recover partitions if necessary using `MSCK REPAIR TABLE abc;` or `ALTER TABLE abc RECOVER PARTITIONS;` if you are on EMR.

If you absolutely need to copy data to another location (and if you are on the Amazon paid EC2 cluster you need reason for spending money on this) use [distcp (distributed copy tool)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html):

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://your/data hdfs://your/data2
```